# StructureMap - Replacing ObjectFactory with Container when initialising

Tags: structuremap

I'm trying to update my code to remove usages of ObjectFactory and just pass around the IContainer object, however one problem I've hit is that in my code to initialise SM, I need access to the container. For example:

```
    var container = new Container(x =>
        {
            x.For<IFoo>().Use(() => new Bar(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IApplicationSettings>().MyConnectionString));
        });
```

The Bar class can't be updated to inject IApplicationSettings. Is there any way I can replace the usage of ObjectFactory here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For<IFoo>().Use(c => new Bar(
        c.GetInstance<IApplicationSettings().MyConnectionString));
});
```

should work.

The `Use` method has an overload that takes an `IContext` lambda, that can be used to access the container.

Comment: Ahh, how did I miss that! Thank you.